# Table data extraction using Form Recogniser

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to extract table data by training different table layout structures. But once the training is completed I am not able to fetch the table data if I am trying to analyze a new file which has a different layout. Is it a limitation from Azure cognitive services.

Answer (score 0):

Was the table extracted automatically and appears in the pageResults section of the JSON output or has a small table icon near it in the UX ? If you are labeling tables and training on tables is your training data all documents from the same format and layout ? If not you should create a model per document type (same format and layout) and then compose all the models together to a single model.

Comment: Is it possible to compose different models into a single model. If so how?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you can tryout with the Konfuzio SDK
to get you started:

```
# pip install konfuzio_sdk
# in the working directory
# konfuzio_sdk init

from konfuzio_sdk.api import get_results_from_segmentation

result = get_results_from_segmentation(doc_id=1111, project_id=111)
# result contains the elements per page
tables_first_page = [r for r in result[0] if r['label'] == 'table']
```

Create a free account [here](https://konfuzio.com/en/pricing/) and upload your training data

https://github.com/konfuzio-ai/document-ai-python-sdk/issues/24